# Abbreviation similar to i.e. and e.g. for "abstract principle illustrated by the previous"?

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations

Pointing out the abstract principle based on an example is very common usage.

---

Suppose we have these to work with:

Elephant < Mammal < Organism

Elephant is an example (subset) of Mammal.

Mammal is an example (subset) of Organism.

---

Usages illustrated based on the above:

**i.e.** - "*id est*" - "it is"

> Here is a mammal (***i.e.*** warm-blooded, milk-producing)

**e.g.** - "*exempli gratia*" - "for example"

> Here is a mammal (***e.g.*** elephant)

**what I am thinking of**

> Here is a mammal (`_._.` organism)

I am looking for something that conveys the last scenario. As you can see,

---

e.g. refers to subsets / examples of a principle / one level more concrete.

What I am thinking of would be a the opposite of e.g.
A superset / generalized principle derived from example(s) / one level more abstract.

Comment: What's wrong with using *i.e.* in the above given examples?

Comment: If I've understood your question, I think the Latin *ergo* (literally: "therefore") would fit nicely, but it obviously neither has nor needs an abbreviation

Comment: i.e. is short for "id est" in Latin. "it is" in English. I don't want to reword or talk about the thing itself (mammals), instead, its superset, a more generalized thing. It would in essence be the opposite of `e.g..` e.g. points out a subset of a principle. I want to be able to point out something as a superset. In programming terms, `e.g.` reffers to an instance of a class. `i.e.` refers to the class itself. What I want would refer to the parent class.

Comment: "ergo" is used for logical continuity. This has nothing to do with logical continuity, but allusion to a superset.

Comment: I think you are looking for a latin acronym for the [subset symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset). Why not just symbolically represent?

Comment: very interesting.

The grammatical order of that requires a certain ordering and both items on one line. If the superset item is within parentheses, the grammar gets broken. Do i lead off with the subset symbol? `mammal (subset symbol organism`? To me, it seems weird because e.g. is supposed to indicate a subset. The item in parentheses is the subset item. But when if a subset symbol is used to indicate the item in parentheses is a superset, why are we using the subset symbol? The order of the grammar has changed.

Comment: Also, editors probably won't be OK with the use of the subset symbol. Most readers and lay people won't recognize it either.

Comment: What would be more consistent with the usage of i.e. and e.g. would be a latin equivalent of denoting that the item in parentheses is the super set. As such, a superset symbol would be used, not subset. But that still doesn't resolve the grammar and ordering issue.

For example, just htink about substituting a logical symbol (subset or superset for `e.g.` in  `Mammal (e.g. elephant)`.  And then think about it for the superset one i am looking for. the grammar and ordering is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You could skew towards the simpler end and just use the indefinite article.

> Here is a mammal (an organism)

The indefinite article indicates that it is a member of that classification, and is only going to be one or two letters but easily understood. It doesn't explicitly declare it's a subset but it does indicate it to be the case.

Comment: It becomes verbally tricky when the example is a long, multi-sentence scenario. but good stuff. like `Yeah, but we don't condone rape (_._. morality trumps aesthetics)` In this case, we can't use "an". I suppose we'd have to break it up into a separate sentence. I thought it might be a neater grammatical structure that drives home the point better if it were a lexical construct.`

Comment: @ahnbizcad *i.e.* works here.  It's not as precise as e.g. (in the opposite direction), but it gets the point across.

Comment: @bcc32 If I can say `dad i.e. granddad`, then one can also say `child i.e. dad`. The latter is wrong, so the prior is wrong too. i.e. is for the thing itself, not a level above or a level below. e.g. crosses a level while i.e. doesn't. To say that i.e. gets the point across stems from a perspective of "good enough" But then we can zoom out the specificity requirement even more and say "e.g." gets the point across too. but it's wrong.

Comment: @ahnbizcad it works for the particular sentence in your comment.  It doesn't work for subsets.  Furthermore, `dad` and `grandad`, (and `child` and `dad`) are not "levels" in the same way `organisms` and `mammals` are.